# using nodejs and forever i get the error Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, forever

I am trying to get forever to start up all my microservices

All the services fail the same way

my forever.json looks like (abbreviated)

```
[
  {
    "uid": "account-service",
    "append": true,
    "watch": true,
    "script": "app.js",
    "sourceDir": "/home/trig/account-service/",
    "workingDir": "/home/trig/account-service/",
    "logFile": "/home/trig/logs/forever.log",
    "outFile": "/home/trig/logs/account_service_out.log",
    "errFile": "/home/trig/logs/account_service_err.log"
  },
```

after starting i do

```
forever list  and get (abbreviated)
/home/trig/.forever/lQOi.log STOPPED
```

if i look at the log

```
data:    account-service:25858 - module.js:471
data:    account-service:25858 -     throw err;
data:    account-service:25858 -     ^
data:    account-service:25858 - Error: Cannot find module '/home/trig/account-service'
data:    account-service:25858 -     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
data:    account-service:25858 -     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
data:    account-service:25858 -     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
data:    account-service:25858 -     at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
data:    account-service:25858 -     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
data:    account-service:25858 -     at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
data:    account-service:25858 - error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

but if i do

```
ls -ls /home/trig/account-service
4 -rw-rw-r--   1308 Dec 28 20:43 app.js
4 drwxrwxr-x   4096 Dec 28 20:43 controllers
4 drwxrwxr-x   4096 Dec 22 05:36 env
4 drwxrwxr-x   4096 Dec 28 20:43 models
4 drwxrwxr-x 154 4096 Dec 28 20:43 node_modules
4 -rw-rw-r--   1 359 Dec 28 20:43 package.json
4 drwxrwxr-x   2 4096 Dec 28 20:43 utils
```

I then tried and changed the paths from absolute to relative ( based on comment below )

```
[
  {
    "uid": "account-service",
    "append": true,
    "watch": true,
    "script": "app.js",
    "sourceDir": "./account-service/",
    "workingDir": "./account-service/",
    "logFile": "/home/trig/logs/forever.log",
    "outFile": "/home/trig/logs/account_service_out.log",
    "errFile": "/home/trig/logs/account_service_err.log"
  },
```

then did

```
forever start account-service ./forever.json
```

and still see the error

```
data:    account-service:1795 - module.js:471
data:    account-service:1795 -     throw err;
data:    account-service:1795 -     ^
data:    account-service:1795 - Error: Cannot find module '/home/trig/account-service'
data:    account-service:1795 -     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
data:    account-service:1795 -     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
data:    account-service:1795 -     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
data:    account-service:1795 -     at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
data:    account-service:1795 -     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
data:    account-service:1795 -     at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
data:    account-service:1795 - error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

if move the forever.json file into the dir /home/trig/account-service ( and remove the other services) and leave the sourceDir and workingDir to absolute path it starts correctly

Comment: Are you doing a forever start ?

Comment: try removing the first / or add . before it  home/trig/account-service/ or ./home/trig/account-service/

Comment: updated the description based on comments from Malice and Amit

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to get forever to work with multiple apps .

I tried http://pm2.keymetrics.io/ and got it working pretty quickly.

so far so good